# How do I fix a JAXB Unsupported Binding Namespace error?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB to generate binding classes from a DTD.

I have a custom binding file `binding.xjb` as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings 
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd "
>

  <jaxb:globalBindings generateValueClass="false">
    <xjc:simple />
  </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

When I run the `xjc` compiler, as follows

```
xjc -dtd -d target/generated-sources/  -b src/main/jaxb/binding.xjb -p com.example src/main/jaxb/my-dtd.dtd
```

I get the following errors

```
[ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb". Perhaps you meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"?
  line 7 of file:/Users/.../Development/projects/fuel/src/main/jaxb/binding.xjb

[ERROR] cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'jaxb:bindings'.
  line 7 of file:/Users/.../Development/projects/fuel/src/main/jaxb/binding.xjb

[ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb". Perhaps you meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"?
  line 9 of file:/Users/.../Development/projects/fuel/src/main/jaxb/binding.xjb

Failed to parse a schema.
```

As far as I can tell, my binding XML is valid. Am I missing something?

I am on Java 1.7 on MacOS (Mavericks)

`java -version` returns

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

and `xjc -version` returns

```
xjc 2.2.4-2
```